Single Datadog agent for Databricks workspace
I followed the setup instructions outlined in this article and everything works fine.  Except for the surprise bill we received from Datadog.
You see, we stand up and destroy Databricks clusters many times.  Every time we create a cluster, a new Datadog agent is created, and Datadog charges us $18 for it, just to have the agent up and running.  Every time.
Is there a way to create a single Datadog agent for the whole Databricks workspace?  We keep 3 workspaces, dev, stg and prod and thus would only have to pay for 3 agents plus whatever data we send to DD.
The alternative we are considering is to send logs via DD API, but I would rather use the agent since it is simpler to use once setup.
